# Itelephony service end call () not working on Samsung GT-S7562 android version 4.0.4

Tags: android, telephony

I am using `Itelephony` service to end the call programmatically. It’s working on HTC android version 4.1 but not working on `SAMSUNG GT-S7562` a`ndroid version 4.0.4` 
Here is my code

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            System.out.println("telephonyManager..."+telephonyManager);
            Class clazz = null;
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                System.out.println("clazz..."+clazz);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Method method = null;
            try 
            {
                method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                System.out.println("method..."+method);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            method.setAccessible(true);
            ITelephony telephonyService = null;
            try 
            {
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {
                telephonyService.endCall();
                Intent   intent = new Intent(OutGoingScreen.this, Dialpad.class);
                startActivity(intent); 
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**My log at is showing this**

```
10-09 09:26:18.938: D/memalloc(4653): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51bf0000 size:9031680 offset:7495680 fd:68
10-09 09:26:19.038: I/System.out(4653): telephonyManager...android.telephony.MSimTelephonyManager@41aefa58
10-09 09:26:19.038: I/System.out(4653): clazz...class android.telephony.MSimTelephonyManager
10-09 09:26:19.038: W/System.err(4653): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getITelephony []
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:685)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at             com.example.demo.OutGoingScreen$1.onClick(OutGoingScreen.java:73)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3567)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-09 09:26:19.058: W/System.err(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 09:26:19.068: W/System.err(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 09:26:19.068: W/System.err(4653):     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-09 09:26:19.068: W/System.err(4653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-09 09:26:19.068: W/System.err(4653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 09:26:19.068: D/AndroidRuntime(4653): Shutting down VM
10-09 09:26:19.078: W/dalvikvm(4653): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c06a68)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.example.demo.OutGoingScreen$1.onClick(OutGoingScreen.java:79)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3567)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-09 09:26:19.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**I have added this in manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

my Itelephony.aidl file is

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;
interface ITelephony {

boolean endCall();

void answerRingingCall();

}
```

Comment: This is a dual-SIM device, so it isn't using the standard `TelephonyManager`. You can see that it is using the class `MSimTelephonyManager` (this is obviously for multi-SIM devices) in the logs. You'll have to do a little more digging to see what methods are available in `MSimTelephonyManager`

Comment: Try using reflection to access the method `getITelephonyMSim()` on that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there looks like you are getting NoSuchMethodException here

```
 method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
```

Its possible that the method is removed form the android framework in the samsumg device.You can test this by trying if the method works in android emulator for android 4.0.4

EDIT: I just checked the source code for Android TelephonyManager.java [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/android/2.3.3/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java). The method does exist in android 4.0.4 source code as well. For me the issue looks like the samsumg device specific. You can test this in another actual device that is running android 4.0.4 to verify. Mine is running 4.3 so cannot test.

Comment: Thanks for replying..... but in emulator the code is not working properly it works only on real devices....any other suggestion?

Comment: okay i will do it as guided by you.will try it on non samsung 4.0.4 and let you know.

Comment: Yes, thats reflection at its worst. When you use reflection to access private members/functions, there is always a chance that the function is not present. You may want to try and use 'class.getMethods()' first to verify if the method actually exists in the device's platform code

Comment: so  now in this case my application is helpless on samsung devices right?...or is there any other way to achieve this.?I am ending/disconnecting outgoing  call from my application on button click.

Comment: I am getting NoSuchMethodException on actual Android 4.0.4 samsung device while it is working fine on emulator.
Did you find any way for this ?

Comment: This isn't a Samsung-specific problem. It is a multi-SIM-specific problem. Multi-SIM devices don't use the standard Android `TelephonyManager`

Answer (score 0):

The `MSimTelephonyManager` class from the Samsung device may bear some similarity to the code from Code Aurora -

https://github.com/gp-b2g/frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/MSimTelephonyManager.java

In addition to using `getITelephonyMSim` instead of `getITelephony` to get the interface to the Phone, the declaration for `endcall` under `ITelephonyMSim` interface so obtained is `boolean endCall(int subscription)` and so you may need to specify the subscription id of the call to hang up. The aidl file in your project would need to be changed to `ITelephonyMSim.aidl` and adapted accordingly.

https://github.com/gp-b2g/frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephonyMSim.aidl

An alternative, assuming `MSimTelephonyManager` extends Android's `TelephonyManager` (which should be the case as the cast in the first line of your code did not throw an exception), is to call `getSuperclass()` to get the `TelephonyManager` class first (or directly get it using `Class.forName("android.telephony.TelephonyManager")`), and then invoke the original `getITelephony`, but depending on the implementation this may only work for the default subscription.